# Jenkins BUILD_LOG evaluates to [...truncated ]

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to set the Build name/Build description based on the outcome of a shell script.
For example, I am executing the following lines in shell:

```
echo `date`

if [ $test == true ]then
echo "BuildSuccess"
else
echo "NoBuild"
fi
```

I am then running the build step "Changes build description". In this, I have added the macro:

```
${BUILD_LOG,maxLines=1}
```

After running the job I get the output as:

```
[SSH] executing...
Thu May 20 00:47:42 PDT 2021
BuildSuccess

[SSH] completed
[SSH] exit-status: 0

New run description is '[...truncated 478 B...]
'
Evaluated macro: '#37'
New run name is '#37'
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Can anyone help me understand why the macro is getting evaluated to [...truncated 478 B...]?

Is there a way I can capture the text "BuildSuccess" from the log?
I am in effect trying to capture the last line of the build log.

Please note that this is a freestyle project and not a pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved a similar issue by:

- `BUILD_LOG_REGEX`
- **email-ext** plugin

Here is a tutorial http://siddesh-bg.blogspot.com/2012/04/using-buildlogregex-in-jenkins-email.html .

By `BUILD_LOG_REGEX` the above mentioned plugin is able to query and extract parts of the build log.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help @Antonio Petricca!
I had tried this earlier but it was not working. The trick I missed was using showTruncatedLines=false